# PDF generated using php TCPDF is not opening in windows system

Tags: php, windows, pdf-generation, cakephp-2.0, tcpdf

I have generated and downloaded a PDF file using php TCPDF. But it is not getting opened in windows system. I am getting an error like "acrobat could not open because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged".

But the file is getting opened in Linux and Mac systems.

Can anyone help me to fine a solution?.. I have searched a lot but didn't got any proper solution.

Comment: Are the first few characters of your file "%PDF-1.7" or something else? If there is something else before, then the problem might be that you've got some HTML being sent before the actual file data. Acrobat is much more picky about things like that, whereas Preview, for example, will just skip right past any garbage and start processing when it sees that token.